# How to display values from ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following ruby hash:

```
values =  [ {"FA1": [{"Act 1": "A"},{"Act 2": "A"}] } ]
```

I need to iterate through the values array to get a string like this

```
cells = "[Act 1     A],[Act 2     B]"
```

Currently, I am trying this :

```
values[0]['FA1'].each do |key, val|
  cells = [#{key} #{val}]
end
```

which gives me the value of

```
#{key} as Act 1 A and #{val} as empty
```

And how can I append these values to a variable separated by a ','?

Comment: That is not a hash, it is an array that contains a hash that contains an array that contains hashes.

Comment: That does put it very precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's weird but anyway...

```
cells = []
values[0]['FA1'].each do |hash|
  hash.keys.each { |key| cells << "[#{key}   #{hash[key]}]" }
end
cells.join(",")
```

This will generate:

```
"[Act 1  A],[Act 2  A]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
values[0]['FA1'].first.map do |key, val|
  "#{key} #{val}"
end.join(",")
```

Comment: that works for the first element, but if i remove .first then the value for val is not displayed.